# php взять первый ключ массива

Tags: php

получаю многомерный массив

```
  [34296]=>
      array(2) {
        [21]=>
        array(5) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(21)
          ["val"]=>
          string(4) "4.00"
          ["per"]=>
          int(2)
          ["type"]=>
          string(5) "float"
          ["rec"]=>
          int(28106)
        }
        [49]=>
        array(5) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(49)
          ["val"]=>
          string(19) "2015-12-01 13:02:23"
          ["per"]=>
          NULL
          ["type"]=>
          string(9) "timestamp"
          ["rec"]=>
          int(28105)
        }
      }
```

как отсуда выдернуть первый ключ (34296)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Взять массив ключей и от него взять первый элемент:

```
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
$firstKey = $keys[0];
```

В PHP7.3+ появилась новая функция

```
$firstKey = array_key_first($my_array);
```

Answer (score 5):

Как и всегда, при разборе массива есть `key` и `value`. В данном случае, если использовать проход по массиву через `foreach($array as $key=>value)`, то в первой итерации будет `34296` а в `value` массив. Опять же, никто не отменял функцию `key($array)` которая возвращает значение ключа массива.

Comment: вот так же неправильно? each($array )['key'];

Comment: Ну если имеется в виду обращение к элементу массива по ключу то тогда надо передавать в $array[$key] и получишь value содержащее тот массив с двумя субмассивами

Comment: @des1roer так тоже получится только если у вас версия PHP >= 5.4

Comment: @des1roer Еще на всякий случай: если брать первый ключ функциями `key($array)` или `each($array)` не забудьте выполнить `reset($array)`

Answer (score 4):

```
reset($array);
echo key($array);
```

Comment: А можно пояснить, что здесь происходит?

Comment: Да, конечно.

`reset($array);` -  Устанавливает внутренний указатель массива на его первый элемент

`key($array);` - Выбирает ключ из массива

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(       
       "34296"=>
       array(
            "21"=>
            array(
              "id"=>21,
              "val"=>"4.00",
              "per"=>2,
              "type"=>"float",
              "rec"=>28106
            ),
            "49"=>
            array(
              "id"=>49,
              "val"=>"2015-12-01 13:02:23",
              "per"=>NULL,
              "type"=>"timestamp",
              "rec"=>28105
            )
          ) 
       );

printf("key_arr = %s", key($arr));
```

Результат:
`key_arr = 34296`